# How to debug a Firefox Add-on SDK extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I am working on code for a Firefox Add-on SDK extension. I want to debug it.

Can we debug it like we do in **Firebug**? Firebug is not working for my add-on.

Comment: Enable developer preferences and then open browser console. Ctrl + Shift + J.

Comment: tHANKS. WHAT I AM NOT ABLE TO dEBUG HTML HERE..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First [result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger) on Google…

> To enable the Add-on Debugger you need to check the "Enable chrome and addon debugging" and "Enable remote debugging" settings in Firefox.
>
> To do this, select "Toggle Tools" from the Web Developer menu in Firefox, open the Developer Tools Settings, and check "Enable chrome and addon debugging" and "Enable remote debugging".
>
> Now open the Add-on Manager. Next to the entry for your add-on you will see a button labeled "Debug". Click this button to launch the debugger.
>
> Next you'll see a dialog asking you to accept an incoming connection. Click "OK", and the debugger will start in a separate window.

Comment: What to do when the debug button appears for other add-ons, but not for mine. Something needs to be done to enable debugging in my code?

Comment: To enable debugging for your addon, open up `about:config` and add this: `extensions.myAddonID.sdk.console.logLevel`  - where myAddonID is the same as your `id` in `package.json`. Set the value to `all`.

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2016:

You can use the [Firefox Add-on Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger).

Use the command [`jpm run --debug`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_run).

Then click on "OK" when asked to accept the incoming connection:

[image: Accept Incoming Connection]?

You will then have a debugger window from which you can select your JavaScript files:

[image: Debugger window]

<sub>I copied most of this answer from [my answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363416/3773011)</sub>.