# How to enable debuging when using jpm run to test a Firefox Add-on SDK extension

Tags: debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

Can somebody tell me what is required to turn on a debugger when testing a Firefox Add-on SDK extension on Windows 7, 64 bit.
I'm launching the add-on via the command line with the command `jpm run`.

I've tried bring up the debugger via <kbd>F12</kbd>. But, I can't see my JavaScript file(s) there.

A step-by-step guide would be useful.

Comment: Related, near duplicate: [How to debug a Firefox Add-on SDK extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286845/how-to-debug-a-firefox-addon/38363577#38363577).

Answer (score 0):

Use the command [`jpm run --debug`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_run).

Then click on "OK" when asked to accept the incoming connection:

[image: Accept Incoming Connection]?

You will then have a debugger window from which you can select your JavaScript files:

[image: Debugger window]